# Move-assignment and reference member

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Copy-assignment for a class with a reference member variable is a no-no because you can't reassign the reference.  But what about move-assignment?  I tried simply `move`ing it but, of course, that destroys the source object when I just want to move the reference itself:

```
class C
{
public:
    C(X& x) : x_(x) {}
    C(C&& other) : x_(std::move(other.x_)) {}
    C& operator=(C&& other)
    {
        x_ = std::move(other.x_);
    }
private:
    X& x_;
};

X y;
C c1(y);

X z;
C c2(z);

c2 = c1; // destroys y as well as z
```

Should I just not be implementing move-assignment and sticking with move-construction only?  That makes `swap(C&, C&)` hard to implement.

Comment: In general if one wants to do non-trivial stuff with references, wouldn't one be using `reference_wrapper<T>` and be done with it? I'm sure that would make move constructor and assignment near-trivial, if not trivial (note not `trivial`).

Comment: @LuisMachuca That seems to work.  If you add it as an answer, I'll upvote it.  Thanks.

Comment: You're sort of missing a declaration for `x_`...

Comment: @ildjarn Whoops! Fixed now.  Thanks.

Comment: I was a bit confused by this question, so for reference: you talk about "move assignment", but the `c2 = c1` line is *not* a move assignment, it is a copy assignment (and thus the reference member is a problem). It should be `c2 = std::move(c1)`, perhaps. You actually can make this work, but the problem is that there's no way to mark the state as being 'invalid' in the moved-from objects. See this example: https://godbolt.org/z/en4aP8

Answer (score 31, accepted):

(Posted as an answer from comment as suggested by the OP)

In general if one wants to do non-trivial stuff with references in C++, one would be using `reference_wrapper<T>`, which is essentially a fancy value-semantic stand-in for a `T&`, then one would be done with it - it already provides (re)assignment and other operations. I'm sure that would make move constructor and assignment near-trivial, if not trivial (note not `trivial` as in per the `is_trivially_*` semantics).

"Reference wrapper" is added to C++03 as part of TR1, and is part of C++11.

Documentation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper

Comment: It is worth promoting comments to answers just so we have more visible up/down voting buttons

Comment: `reference_wrapper` is not movable, so this does not really solve the problem. As far as I can tell, if you want your class to contain a reference and be movable, you have to use a pointer.

Comment: @Nemo A class that contains an `std::reference_wrapper` can also have a copy constructor by rvalue / assignment operator by rvalue, so doesn't that serve to answer the original question? In the above case it would allow you to use all the defaults, using the Rule of Zero.

Answer (score 2):

A reference is, in some sense, a `T *const` with syntactic sugar on top to auto-derefence, auto-capture, and auto-lifetime extend temporaries.  (note that this is not quite true, but often is in practice and practicality)

If you want a reseatable reference, C++ has those: they are called pointers.  You can use an accessor to replace dereferencing with a function call if you like.  The remaining feature (temporary lifetime extension) that is hard to emulate does not apply to `struct` members.

Comment: Pointers have weaker semantics than just reseatable references.  For example, you can assign `NULL` to them.  More importantly, they don't document the intent at all (write-code-to-be-read-not-executed etc.).