# Is it possible to create a only movable class with const / reference member?

Tags: c++

All is in the question. I tried :

```
#include <vector>

class Foo
{
    int & _x;

    public:
        Foo(int x) :
            _x(x)
        {}

        Foo(Foo && other) :
            _x(other._x)
        {}
        Foo & operator=(Foo && other) = default;

    private:
        Foo(Foo const &) = delete;
        Foo & operator=(Foo const &) = delete;
};

int main(void)
{
    int a, b;
    std::vector<Foo> vec;

    vec.push_back(Foo(a));
    vec.push_back(Foo(b));
    vec.erase(vec.begin());
    return 0;
}
```

but it cannot compile because `Foo & operator=(Foo && other)` is deleted by default.

I tried to delete this operator, to force the compiler using the constructor by move, but it tried to use the copy constructor.

Is it possible to move an object with a reference member ?

If not, why ?

Thanks.

EDIT : I have already read [Move-assignment and reference member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20484344/move-assignment-and-reference-member) but it does not answer my question : I wonder why `Foo & operator=(Foo const &)` is used by the compiler, while `Foo(Foo && other)` could work.

And I cannot understand why it is not possible to move a class with reference member.

Comment: classes with reference members can be copy constructed and move constructed, but cannot be copy assigned or move assigned.  The problem isn't the move, the problem is the assign (operator=)

Comment: And why std::vector use the operator= and not the move constructor ? Have not they the same behavior ?

Comment: No. One constructs and the other assigns.  vector uses constructors for `push_back`, but `erase` requires assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that [`erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) requires that the element type be [`MoveAssignable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/MoveAssignable). This is simply because of the way that `erase` is typically implemented: it walks the vector after the erased element (or elements), move-assigning to the erased slot:

```
for (; j != end; ++i, ++j)
    *i = std::move(*j);
for (; i != end; ++i)
    i->~T();
```

This could be implemented differently, using move construction, but that would be inefficient where a move assignment operator exists (which is most of the time) and difficult to get exception-safe:

```
for (; j != end; ++i, ++j)
{
    i->~T();
    new (&*i) T(std::move(*j));  // what if this throws?
}
for (; i != end; ++i)
    i->~T();
```

You could work around this by using another strategy to get the effect of `erase`, for example:

```
vec = std::vector<Foo>(
  std::make_move_iterator(std::next(vec.begin())),
  std::make_move_iterator(vec.end()));
```

`Foo` will still not be very useful, precisely because a type with a reference member cannot be move-assignable ([Move-assignment and reference member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20484344/move-assignment-and-reference-member?lq=1)); you should consider whether you can use `reference_wrapper` instead.

Comment: I wanted my reference to be public (or using a `type * const`) : so everybody could use it without modify the adress value. But a reference_wrapper does not work, since we have to use `get()`.