# Make a class with an reference member copyable and moveable

Tags: c++

I have a class

```
class Route
{
    public:
    Route(std::vector<int> locationIds, const ILocationSource&);
    double getRouteLength() const;
    bool operator<(const Route&);

    private:
    std::vector<int> locationIds_;
    const ILocationSource& locationSource_;
};
```

`getRouteLength()` calculatates the route length by iterating through the `locationIds_` and getting the coordinates from the `ILocationSource`:

```
class ILocationSource
{
    public:
    virtual Location getLocation(size_t n) = 0;
};

struct Location
{
    double x, y, z;
}
```

I don't want to store the coordinates in `Route` because `Location` is about 6 times larger than the `int` IDs which could be significant if I have a lot of long routes in memory.

The problem is that `Route::locationSource_` makes it hard to implement move semantics, so trying to to call `std::sort()` on a `std::vector<Route>` complains.

The simple solution would be to change `locationSource_` into a pointer to const, I guess, but I was wondering if anyone can see a better solution or pattern. Singletons aren't an option because there could be several realizations of the `ILocationService` at the same time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20484344/move-assignment-and-reference-member

Comment: please provide a reproducible example

Comment: The problem with std::reference_wrapper is that I have to create a temporary copy based on my original vector, and copy assign the original to the temporary after sorting.

Comment: I don't think a reproducible example is necessary. I can hack the code until it compiles and works myself. The question title probably isn't the best. What I really want to know is if there is some way of satisfying the dependency between `Route` and `ILocation` that keeps `Route` movable/copyable.

Comment: About you needing to use reference instead of values: Do some actual math on expected memory use. Using indirection is probably going to be a performance hit. Unless you need the *shared* coordinates to change, 3 doubles is so little that using a copy (wraped in a POD struct) is probably much better.

Comment: Each route can contain hundreds of `Location`s, and I may have hundreds of routes. So the 20 byte increase could actually be significant.

Comment: @carlsb3rg 3 doubles is 24 bytes. If you have just paltry 24 megabytes of memory for this purpose, that already fits a million coordinates, or 1000 routes with 1000 coordinates each. You are talking about only hundreds in your comment... Memory use is not an issue for you here. Processing speed may be, depending on your algorithms, and indirection is going to hurt there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just use [shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) instead of a reference:

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<const ILocationSource> locationSource_;
```

It solves your copying/moving problem, and you get (shared) ownership over the `ILocationSource` instance, that guarantees `ILocationSource` will be alive as long as `Route` needs it.

Other than that, consider passing `locationIds` by ref or `const` ref.

Comment: I ended up using `std::shared_ptr`, and it worked out well. Thank you for the suggestion.